# ошибка при проверки флагов TCP

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

при захвате сетевых пакетов, программа останавливается после захвата сетевого TCP пакета
Ether / IP / TCP 44.239.146.66:https > 192.168.0.10:64388 PA / Raw
и выводит ошибку

if packet[TCP].flags & (TCP.flags.R | TCP.flags.F | TCP.flags.U):
AttributeError: 'FlagsField' object has no attribute 'R'

очевидно ошибка в строке и в синтаксисе

```
    if packet[TCP].flags & (TCP.flags.R | TCP.flags.F | TCP.flags.U):

        return True
```

P.S. я ультра-новичок и каких то очевидных вещей могу не знать